# Send RDLC in Email as Body

Tags: html, winforms, rdlc, reportviewer

I Already Digging for 5 hours but nothing to found. Is there any way to generate the rdlc into HTML. I tried RDLC to Image but my problem is, the generated image is slice in half.

Comment: This might help https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32109/Send-Mail-and-Print-Report-in-Report-Viewer-Contro

Comment: @mchawre as i understand in the article, its sending excel us a attachment which is not fullfill my goal. Althought thank you for the link for future reference in sending report in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution(even though is not best answer). So basically, convert first to Excel then convert the excel into html then read all the text. I use the FreeSprite.XLS to convert the excel into html.

[Freespire.xls Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.XLS/)

here is my code

```
  private string GenerateHTMLReport(ReportViewer rv)
    {
        string mimeType,
            encoding,
            fileNameExtension;
        Warning[] warnings=null;
        string[] streamIds=null;

        //Export report
        byte[] exportBytes = rv.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings);

        //convert to excel
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("report.xls", FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(exportBytes, 0, exportBytes.Length);
        fs.Close();

        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        workbook.LoadFromFile("report.xls");

        //convert Excel to HTML  
        Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
        sheet.SaveToHtml("report.html");

        string html =System.IO.File.ReadAllText("report.html");
        return "";
    }
```

generated HTML Code.
[image]

generated HTML in Preview.
[image]

Hopefully someone will found it helpful.